How to delete a tag created by mistake?
I just edited this post, and I created a new tag by mistake.
I was about to add a new characters but then realized it wasn't necessary and went on to delete the char that I had just begun typing in the tab bar.
The existing tags reverted to their original display translation and meaning-in-context, so I thought everything was good, but after I hit edit, the system actually created the tag with the extra characters as if I never deleted them.
So now there is a meaning-in-contextchar tag.
How can I delete this tag? I think I don't have enough privileges to do that...

If there's no questions with the tag, it's effectively "deleted".

@Becky李蓓 but I can still search it in the Tags section of the main site. It also comes up when editing tags or asking a question

Yes, it's soft-deleted in 24 hours. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it

@dROOOze Want to whip that up as an answer?

In most cases, you don't need to do anything. All you need to do is to wait until 03:00 UTC, and tags which don't have any associated questions will be effectively deleted (hidden). This cleanup occurs every day.
If the tag gains an associated question, the tag needs to be edited out of the question, and the next cleanup cycle will trigger a soft-delete.
See How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or “zombie”) tags?
